# Stop greasmonkey script from continuously running after page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have written a script that enter some information into a form and submits the form. The problem is, upon submission of the form, the page refreshes. When the page reloads, it prompts the script to run again resulting in an endless loop. The only solution i have now is to hit the escape key to stop the script from running once it has already completed once. Is there any code that will prevent this endless loop?

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way I can think of is to submit the form to a page that doesn't match the @include of the same script.

For example:

```
// @include http://domain.com/page.php
```

and then you submit the form to http://domain.com/page.php**#something_else**